# divide large VC++ .NET GUI header file

Tags: .net, user-interface, refactoring, visual-c++-2005

I've inherited a GUI in the format of a 10,000 line Visual C++ .NET `Form1.h` file and 3 megabyte `Form1.resx`. The previous author essentially put down lots of buttons to mock up the interface, implemented a few things, and then ran out of steam. My task is to finish it. The management does not want to lose their "investment" on it, and I'd rather keep whatever is done as well.

Is there anything I can do to divide this monster into smaller files, and perhaps even organize it somewhat? Right now, it's large enough that editing tasks are slow. It can only get slower. The existing functionality is implemented directly in the `Form1.h` file, so preferably I'd rather keep the actions/events attached to the UI elements.

I just figured out how to create a new managed resource file and copy-paste UI elements, but that doesn't include certain properties such as names, or events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The management does not want to lose their "investment" on it

This is a flawed position. Whether it's the right move to throw something out and start over depends on how much work there is left to complete it, *not* on how much work has already been done. At this point, they're just throwing good money after bad.

Treat the existing application as a prototype design and implement it properly from the ground up, because that will probably be *faster* than trying to fix up this monstrosity.

Comment: Perhaps, but are you basing your conclusion on my own cynical wording, or is there more to it? The purpose of my question is to reduce the amount of work to complete it, so if there's an answer to exactly what I asked, that may change the decision you debate.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I'm basing my recommendation on your description of the problem, but the point about only looking at the remaining work when deciding on a course of action is true regardless.

Comment: Whether to throw out incomplete code doesn't depend on how much remains, it depends on how broken it is. *Only* looking at the remaining work completely ignores existing progress, which is clearly not the right analysis.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The first rule of investment is to *ignore sunk costs*. Don't get attached to them. They're gone no matter what choice you make. If it will take more work to get the existing code into a servicable state than to write it from scratch, throw it out and start over, because *that will cost you less*.

Comment: My own words presupposed that. The key is " **If** it will take more work…", which is what I'm trying to determine here.